# Checking for permission and redirecting gives err_too_many_redirects?

Tags: facebook, redirect, permissions

I am tweaking my application with some extra code, like checking if the permissions we need have been allowed by the user (maybe he has changed it after his first visit).

```
$permissions_needed = array('publish_stream,read_stream');
foreach($permissions_needed as $perm) {
   if( !isset($permissions_list['data'][0][$perm]) || $permissions_list['data'][0][$perm] != 1 ) {
      $login_url_params = array(
         'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream',
         'fbconnect' =>  1,
         'next' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        //redirect_uri => 'https://www.mydomain.com/fb_app/'
      );
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);
      header("Location: {$login_url}");
      exit();
   }
```

How do i fix this? And when to use next vs redirect_uri as params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you only prompt your users to allow extended permissions (or any permission) only when they are performing the action that requires that permission?
Here is a link to a [SO Question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3388367/check-for-extended-permissions-with-new-facebook-javascript-sdk) detailing how to request permissions with the Facebook JS SDK.
If your use removed a certain permission it might have been because he/she did not know why your application needs that permission.  By requesting for the permission only when the user performs that action, and maybe including a short explication on why you are requesting this permission, the users might be inclined to re-allow your application the permission in debate.

**EDIT**
For re-directions I usually use a JS redirect.  Like this :

```
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
      'req_perms' => implode(",",$requiredPermissions), 
      'fbconnect' =>  1,
      'redirect_uri' =>'YOUR_URL'
    ));
echo "<script language=javascript>";
echo "top.location.href = '".$url."';";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: you are right about the "application-needs-that-permission", but this is part of my test code and i like know how to prompt  the permission box when the if statement returns true. Simple echoing "Give us the right permission" works. I am using the same $login_url_parms as the first time a user visits.

Comment: try removing your `$facebook->getLoginUrl`, `header`, and `exit` calls from your while statement.  Put a `$has_all_perms` flag in there instead, and a `break;` statement.  Then check that after the `wile loop` has ended.

Comment: hmm, and how would i prompt for the permission? `if($has_all_perms == 0) {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);
    header("Location: {$login_url}");
    exit();
}` gives the same error

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer above.